# How to reset scroll behaviour on zoom out?

Tags: javascript, charts, lightningchart

I am using the lightning charts(in this case the chartXY) by arction for real time data visualization in my react application.When I zoom in using the mouse wheel or the zoom rectangle the chart stops scrolling as expected.When I zoom out the chart starts scrolling but does not follow the interval I set it to.Is there any way to reset the zoom to go back to the current point in real time.

X Axis configuration:

- progressive scroll
- interval(0,3000) //in milliseconds I presume

Series configuration:

- data pattern Datapatterns.horizontalProgressive

I also cannot find a method to control the zoom Out rectangle please let me know if this is present.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi were you able to zoom out to the set interval. I am also having same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when the zooming rectangle is used to zoom out, LightningChart JS will fit the view to the current data. In your case you would like to go back to the original axis interval. You can attach a listener to [`Axis.onScaleChange`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/axis.html#onscalechange) event. In this listener you can check if the new scale range would be larger than the original range. And if it is, set the axis interval back to the original range.

```js
series.axisX
    .onScaleChange((start, end) => {
        if (end - start > intervalSize) {
            series.axisX.setInterval(end - intervalSize, end)
        }
    })
```

The "Zoom out rectangle" is called "Fitting rectangle" in LightningChart JS. You can change the visual style of it with [`ChartXY.setFittingRectangleFillStyle`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/chartxy.html#setfittingrectanglefillstyle) and [`ChartXY.setFittingRectangleStrokeStyle`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/chartxy.html#setfittingrectanglestrokestyle)

```js
chart.setFittingRectangleFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorRGBA(255,0,0,125)}))
```

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    DataPatterns,
    AxisScrollStrategies,
    SolidFill,
    ColorRGBA
} = lcjs

const {
    createProgressiveTraceGenerator
} = xydata

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

// Create progressive line series.
const series = chart.addLineSeries({
    dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive
})

// configure axis
const intervalSize = 100
series.axisX
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)
    .setInterval(0, intervalSize)

// limit the axis interval to the original interval size
series.axisX
    .onScaleChange((start, end) => {
        if (end - start > intervalSize) {
            series.axisX.setInterval(end - intervalSize, end)
        }
    })

// "Zoom out rectangle"
chart.setFittingRectangleFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorRGBA(255,0,0,125)}))

// Generate traced points stream using 'xydata'-library.
createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
    .setNumberOfPoints(1000)
    .generate()
    .setStreamRepeat(true)
    .toStream()
    .forEach(data => {
        series.add(data)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.2.1/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```